# Corrupted files when downloading with HTTP

Tags: http, tcpip, adsl, packet-sniffer, packetloss

With my UMTS connection most archives > 50 MB are corrupted when downloading them via HTTP. If I switch to HTTPS the problem is gone. The problem should not reside in my network, because I have an additional ADSL connection. When I switch to this connection 100 % of downloaded archives are ok.

My thought was that the problem should be: HTTP has no hash proof for the packets. The proof from TCP is weak. When there are a lot of corrupted packages transferred by the UMTS connection, some should come through the TCP proof and the result is a corrupted file. But when I monitor the connection with wireshark and filter "tcp.analysis.lost_segment" I don't get more errors than with the ADSL connection (in fact it has even more). So this should not be the problem.

If I switch to WLAN connection the problems are gone! What does that mean? Does the WLAN protocol some additional proof or has the ethernet card of my modem a defect? But shouldn't I see a lot of corrupt packages in this case via Ethernet?

Where do my corrupted files come from?

Comment: Your mobile operator might be doing their best *"to improve your internet experience"* and run a transparant proxy or similar as for instance a web accelerator or security gateway etc. (and is apparently failing miserably). - What happens you switch to HTTPS?

Comment: It's quite possible that what HBruijn is saying is true. Run some VPN to verify that.

Comment: Sorry for my absence... If I switch to HTTPS the problem is gone. I had now some time to test again. If I switch to WLAN connection the problems are gone! What does that mean? Does the WLAN protocol some additional proof or has the ethernet card of my modem a defect? But shouldn't I see a lot of corrupt packages in this case?